# Enigmail Thunderbird pinentry requests all passwords to all secret keys

Tags: gpg, thunderbird, gpg-agent, pinentry, enigmail

I want to read a GPG encrypted email using Thunderbird Enigmail from Account.1@mail.com and Edit > Account Settings > Account.1 > OpenPGP Security has "Use specific OpenPGP key ID" selected.

However, when I select the message in order to read, Thunderbird or Enigmail (??) is asking gpg to launch pinentry for every key on my keychain that I own (Account.1@mail.com, Account.2@mail.com, etc.). This is true even if correct password already in 5-minute cache. Clicking "Cancel" a dozen times is annoying.

Can I configure so that pinentry only asks me for password for immediate use (decrypt as Account.1@mail.com) rather than all secret and public keys on keychain that I own?

Comment: This is also an issue under Windows.